# Create a dictionary from a formatted file

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to be able to read in a file, `post.md`, like this:

```
title: Some Title
slug: some-title
author: Joe Smith
date: Jan 23 2015
tags: a, b, c, d

This is the first paragraph of the post.

This is another paragraph.
```

and generate a python dictionary like this:

```
post = {
    "title": "Some Title",
    "slug": "some-title",
    "author": "Joe Smith",
    "title": datetime.date(2015, 1, 23),
    "tags": ["a", "b", "c", "d",],
    "body": "This is the first paragraph of the post.\n\nThis is another paragraph."
}
```

It is acceptable to modify the file input slightly, but can't go full yaml because I want markdown highlighting. Maybe someone who knows [pelican's code base](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican) better than myself can figure out how it is done there.

Comment: Use the python [`Markdown`](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/index.html) package with the `Meta-Data` extension. A complete example is provided [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/meta_data.html).

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it is exactly what I am looking for. I wish you had posted as an answer so I could reward you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Carl Groner suggested, this can be done with the [Meta-Data Extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/meta_data.html) to [Python Markdown](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/index.html).